# Determine the location of a Java package

Tags: java, classpath

I need to find the jar from a Java project that provides a certain logical Java package (e.g. `com.example.functionality`), but there are hundreds of them, and their names aren't particularly useful.

How to find out the mappings that are created between dirs/files/jars and packages/classes?

Comment: There are no explicit mappings as far as I know. In the common case, classes are looked up by the classloader going through the list of classpath entries one-by-one, trying to load the class from each one in turn, and using the first one it finds. After the class is loaded, it's kept cached in memory, and the classloader no longer needs to care where it came from.

Comment: are you trying to find this once, or at runtime in code?

Comment: If you're using an IDE, that should tell you. If not, i'd just grep the jar files for the name of your class. Class names are encoded as filenames, and filenames are uncompressed in jar files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

obj.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()

See: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html)

Comment: You want a `.getLocation()` on the end of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("com.example.functionality");

// eg. /com/example/functionality.class
String classfilePath = '/' + myClass.getName().replace(".", "/") + ".class";

URL location = myClass.getResource(classfilePath);
```

That URL will be the JAR file (or the class folder if it isn't in a jar).
Slightly hacky though - may not work for all classloaders.

Comment: That URL will point to the class file, which will be inside the JAR or directory. Not too hard to go from there to a URL to the actual directory, though.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-off search, http://www.jarfinder.com/ is handy.  It has in impressive index, which seems to know about everything in Maven Central as well as many other download sites around the web, and lets you search by class name to find which JARs contain that class.